# Button draggable and at the same time contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have button that when clicked creates another button.

```
$('#button')
.click(function (eventClick, posX, posY) {
    var htmlData = '<div id="btn' + $.count + '" class="draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable" ' + 'data-page="' + $.page + '" ';
    if (posX != null && posY != null) {
        htmlData += 'style="left:' + Math.abs(posX - 439) + 'px; top:' + Math.abs(posY - 124) + 'px;""';
    }

    htmlData += '><button id="editable' + $.count + '" style="width:100%; height:100%">Button</button><a href="#" class="delete" style="z-index:999"></a></div>';

    $('.demo').append(htmlData);
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        containment: "#workspace",
        scroll: false,
        cancel: false,

    })
        .resizable({
            containment: "#workspace"
        })
        .click(function () {
            if ($(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging')) {
                return;
            }
            $(this).draggable("option", "disabled", true);
            $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        })
        .blur(function () {
            $(this).draggable('option', 'disabled', false);
            $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
        });
    $('a.delete').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        btnID = $(this).closest('.draggable')[0].id;
        //alert('Now deleting "'+objID+'"');
        $('#' + btnID + '').remove();
    });

    $.count++;
});
```

This javascript fires when the create button is clicked, now this new button that is nested in a `div` has attributes draggable, resizable, deletable, and the content should supposedly be editable. Now my problem arise when I'm editing the text, the whole `button` tag is erased when I completely erase the content of it. I'm just left with I think a `div` tags. I can't seem to find what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you are setting the contentEditable attribute on the div, because it has the 'draggable' class. This means everything inside the DIV is fair game to erase, including the button. If you want the text of the button to be editable, you should set the contentEditable attribute on the button instead.